# Proving Two Triangles are Congruent with an Angle and a Pair of Congruent Sides

Tags: geometry, triangles

I have the following as givens:

1. $\angle$ A $\cong$ $\angle$ D
2. Side AC $\cong$ Side DF
3. AB + BC = DE + EF

I need to prove that $\triangle$ ABC $\cong$ $\triangle$ DEF using the above. I keep on running into the issue that I don't know how to establish that side AB $\cong$ side DE, or that side BC $\cong$ side EF. I tried proving that $\triangle$ ABC is isoceles, but that only succeeded in proving that side AB $\cong$ side BC. I also tried playing around with the equality above but couldn't parse it into something meaningful. Any ideas about how to move forward would be very appreciated.

Comment: A simple drawing will show you that this is not true.

Comment: How do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be on ray $AB$ such that $BC=BX$ and $Y$ be on ray $DE$ such that $EF=EY$

Now as $AC=DF, \angle XAC=\angle YDF, AX=DY\implies \Delta AXC \cong DYF \implies \angle CXA=\angle FYD$

Again, $\angle CBA=2\angle CXA=2\angle FYD=\angle FED$, From  **AAS** $\Delta ABC \cong DEF$

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! This is really helpful.

Comment: How did you determine that AX = DY?

Comment: @tryingtodomath $AX=AB+BX=AB+BC=DE+EF=DE+EY=DY$